# What should I use instead of spread operator for Chrome in Math.max(...arr)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, spread-syntax

I know that spread operator is not supported by Chrome browser. And now I have this piece of code:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var max = Math.max(...arr);
console.log('Max: '+ max);
```

The above code always gives me this error in Chrome(But is works on Mozilla and Safari):

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
```

I have searched a lot all over the net but I could not find any useful answer for this case. So please help me to find out what should I use instead of spread operator in chrome to do the same task carried out in the code.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

For array as parameter to the `Math.max()` function use

```
Math.max.apply(null, arr);
```

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var max = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
console.log('Max: '+ max);
```

Comment: Passing anything other than `Math` as the first argument to `apply` will make `Math.max` run in a different context from normal. Not saying it won't work in browsers I tried this in, but it could fail if the implementation required the default `Math` context.

Comment: `Math.max` implementation doesn't use object instance variable - there is no reason to do so. The function implementation would just iterate over arguments and find the maximum one. According to [official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) it is a static method of `Math`

Comment: Like I said, I'm not aware of any implementations where it will fail, just that such an implementation is possible, although I can't think of a good reason why it would implemented in such a way.

Comment: But you are aware that it is a static method.

Comment: Sure, but all methods have a context, static or instance. `console.log.apply(null, [1, 2, 3])` will fail in the Firefox and Chrome console, but will work in Firebug. It all depends on the implementation.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara—the (execution) context from which a function call is made has no effect on its *this* value (arrow functions excepted). However, it would make sense to use `Math.max.apply(Math, argArray)` even if just for clarity.

Comment: @RobG I'm not sure I follow what you're saying. The execution context/this value does change based on how it is called (and of course, the context in which is was called from is irrelevant). Passing `null` to `apply` will make the `this` value `null` (or `window` if not using strict mode) https://jsfiddle.net/0Loctnr2/

Comment: @RobG passing `Math` as the owner (or contex) object to `apply()` method should be considered as error, because you can not create an object of `Math`  : `var x = new Math(); // error`

Comment: But `Math` is the context for methods on the `Math` object when called `Math.method()`. See for yourself: `Math.myMethod=function(){console.log(this===Math);};Math.myMethod();` In JavaScript, `this` is applicable to all method calls.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Can you do this to your method? `var x = {};
Math.myMethod().apply(x);`

Comment: @MaxZoom Depends what `myMethod()` returns. In your example you are calling it, so it would need to return a function. You would be able to do this: `var x = {}; Math.myMethod=function(){console.log(this===x);}; Math.myMethod.apply(x);`

Comment: @MaxZoom—Math methods are generally called as methods of the Math object because they are properties of the Math object. There is no requirement in the specification for **any** Math method to have its *this* set to the Math (or any) object. The argument to use Math as the *this* value for Math methods is not supported by the language specification, it's just a suggestion for readable code. The Math object itself is a plain Object with zero special properties.

Comment: @MaxZoom Thanks for your answer. I tried it and it worked on my code. Also this discussion is great though seems a little advanced for me.